# how to apply a function to each row of a pandas dataframe, where the input to the function is the elements in the row in the form of a list

Tags: pandas, function, row

I would like to apply a function to each row of a dataframe.  The function takes in each row of the dataframe as a list.
For example, I am computing a new column called 'membership' that takes the entire row of the data frame as input.  But the input needs to be in the form of a list.  The code below is not working.

```
df_sample['membership'] = df_sample.apply(lambda row: 
                     cluster_pred(df_sample.values.tolist()), axis = 1)
```

Comment: in the above example, my function is called 'cluster_pred().  It takes a list of the elements of each row of the dataframe.  The function returns a value that goes to the column 'membership'.  My trouble is - how do I convert the elements of the row into a list before my function can act on it

Comment: `df_sample.values.tolist()` will create a list of lists. Is this what you need for the function? Or just one row?

Comment: @SKPS - just one row.

Comment: `df_sample.iloc[row].values.tolist()` ?

Comment: @SKPS - no luck - I got this as an error: positional indexers are out-of-bounds', 'occurred at index 000045de-64a0-4814-a64a-fcf838418f442020-03-08'

Comment: i know that df_sample.values.tolist()[0] accesses the first list in the list of lists etc.

Comment: `df_sample.values.tolist()[row]` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230674/discussion-between-skps-and-nanda-nathan).

Comment: df_sample['membership'] = df_sample.apply(lambda row: cluster_pred(row.tolist()), axis=1)

Proposed by TDY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your lambda, you've defined the incoming row as `row`, so you can just pass `row.tolist()`:

```py
df_sample['membership'] = df_sample.apply(lambda row:
    cluster_pred(row.tolist()), axis=1)
```